# ¿Cómo mostrar el cuadro de "Cómo llegar" en mi mapa?

Tags: javascript, html5

Tal y como dice en el título, mi pregunta es esa. De que manera puedo disponer de ese cuadro de información en mi mapa?

Les dejo la imagen para que tengan idea de a que me refiero.

[image]

Comment: Por la imagen supongo que tienes un mapa hecho con la API de Google Maps. ¿Podrías compartir el código que tienes para abrir un cuadro como el que muestras (aunque no incluya el "Cómo llegar")?

Comment: Bienvenido a [Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour), 
puede tratar de mejorar su pregunta mirando este [enlace](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
es posible que su pregunta sea cerrada o puesta en espera no se lo tome a mal, 
para mas información consulte el siguiente [enlace](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). 
Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En realidad es más sencillo de lo que parece. No especificas si tienes el mapa; de todos modos pondré mi respuesta como un *how to*.

Lo primero es nuestro marcado:

```
<body onload="initMap()">
  <section class="map">
    <button id="how-arrive">¿Cómo llegar?</button>
    <div id="map"></div>
  </section>
</body>
```

Cuando el body cargue, se iniciará el mapa. Puedes incluso crear el mapa sobre un evento del usuario. Luego, debemos definir la función `initMap`.

```
function initMap() {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
    var origin = new google.maps.LatLng(
     position.coords.latitude,
     position.coords.longitude
    );
    var destination = new google.maps.LatLng(
      -8.1156425,
      -79.015092
    );
    createMap(origin, destination);
  }, onError);
}
```

En esta función lo que hacemos es uso de la [API de Geolocalización](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/WebAPI/Using_geolocation) de HTML5. Es simple, si el navegador soporta dicha API, al ejecutarla nos pedirá permiso para rastrear nuestra ubicación. La función `getCurrentPosition` nos pasa nuestra posición -que es un objeto- por callback.

De este obejeto podemos obtener nuestras coordenadas mediante la propiedad `coords` y podemos acceder a nuestra `latitud` y `longitud`. Por último, creamos objetos `LatLng` (propios de GoogleMaps) pasándole las coordenadas del usuario y las nuestras (origin y target). Finalmente, creamos el mapa pasándole el `origen` y `destino`.

**createMap**

```
function createMap(origin, destination) {
  var mapData = {
    zoom: 15,
    center: origin,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }

  // creamos el mapa y el marcador
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapData);
  var originMarker = createMarker(map, origin, 'Tu estás aquí');
  var destinationMarker = createMarker(map, destination, 'Estamos aquí', true);

  // vamos a dibujar la ruta cuando se haga click en '¿Cómo llegar?'
  // y a eliminar los marcadores, ya que cuando se dibuja la ruta
  // google maps añade dos marcadores para ambas posiciones.
  var howArrive = document.getElementById('how-arrive');
  howArrive.addEventListener('click', function() {
    drawRoute(map, origin, destination);
    originMarker.setMap(null);
    destinationMarker.setMap(null);
  });
}
```

En la función `createMap` creamos el mapa especificando opciones como:

- `zoom`: es el nivel de zoom del mapa
- `center`: un objeto `LatLng` que servirá como referencia para el centrado automático.
- `mapTypeId`: sirve para especificar el tipo de mapa por defecto. En este caso es `ROADMAP` o "carretera" en español.

Con estas opciones creamos el mapa. Luego, creamos los marcadores para indicar **dónde está el usuario** y **dónde nos encontramos nosotros.**. Finalmente, seleccionamos el botón `¿Cómo llegar?` y le añadimos una función que se ejecutará cuando el usuario lo pulse. Esta función es la encargada de pintar la ruta: `drawRoute`; además, eliminamos los marcadores que hemos creado, ya que cuando se dibuja la ruta, google maps añade dos marcadores (A y B) para ambas posiciones. Pero antes, veamos la función `createMarker`.

**createMarker**

```
function createMarker(map, position, title, isDestination) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    draggable: true, // permite moverse
    animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE,
    position: position,
    title: title
  });
  // si se va a crear el marcador destino, entonces
  // se le pone un marcador personalizado (amarillo)
  if(isDestination) {
    marker.setIcon('https://i.imgur.com/TFDuAHr.png?1');
  }
  return marker;
}
```

Esta función es bastante simple. Recibe los siguientes parámetros:

- map: el objeto `google.maps.Map` que acabamos de crear.
- draggable: le permite al marcador moverse.
- animation: la animación que tendrá el marcador. En este caso es `Bounce`.
- position: el objeto `LatLng`.
- title: el texto que se mostrará al poner el cursor sobre el marcador.
- isDestination: si es el marcador destino, se pondrá otro ícono.

Finalmente, la función `drawRoute` para pintar la ruta entre ambas posiciones.

**drawRoute**

```
function drawRoute(map, origin, destination) {
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  directionsService.route({
    origin: origin,
    destination: destination,
    // puedes escoger entre 'WALKING', 'TRANSIT' y 'BICYCLING'
    travelMode: 'DRIVING'
  }, function(response, status) {
    if(status === 'OK') {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    } else {
      alert('No se pudo establecer el recorrido. ', status);
    }
  });
}
```

Lo primero que hacemos es instanciar las clases `DirectionsService` y `DirectionsService`. Luego, hacemos que `directionsService` envuelva al mapa y finalmente crea la ruta mediante el método `route`. A este método le debes pasar un objeto con los siguientes datos:

- origin: el objeto `LatLng` origen.
- destination: el objeto `LatLng` destino.
- travelMode: sirve para decirle cómo pintar la ruta de acuerdo a cómo el usuario piensa viajar: `DRIVING`, `WALKING`, `BICYCLING` y `TRANSIT`.

---

### Código completo

En este ejemplo voy a mostrar cómo llegar desde el Aeropuerto Internacional Jorge Chávez (Lima) al distrito de Los Olivos.

```js
/**
 * @author Mitsu G
 *
 * Este ejemplo demuestra cómo pintar la ruta desde 
 * el Aeropuerto Jorge Chávez hasta Los Olivos.
 */

function initMap() {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
    var origin = new google.maps.LatLng(
     /*position.coords.latitude,
     position.coords.longitude*/
      -12.0240527, -77.1142247
    );
    var destination = new google.maps.LatLng(
      -11.956821, -77.0798796
    );
    createMap(origin, destination);
  }, onError);
}

function createMap(origin, destination) {
  var mapData = {
    zoom: 13,
    center: origin,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  
  // creamos el mapa y el marcador
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapData);
  var originMarker = createMarker(map, origin, 'Tu estás aquí');
  var destinationMarker = createMarker(map, destination, 'Estamos aquí', true);
  
  // vamos a dibujar la ruta cuando se haga click en '¿Cómo llegar?'
  var howArrive = document.getElementById('how-arrive');
  howArrive.addEventListener('click', function() {
    drawRoute(map, origin, destination);
    originMarker.setMap(null);
    destinationMarker.setMap(null);
  });
}

function createMarker(map, position, title, isDestination) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    draggable: true, // permite moverse
    animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE,
    position: position,
    title: title
  });
  // si se va a crear el marcador destino, entonces
  // se le pone un marcador personalizado (amarillo)
  if(isDestination) {
    marker.setIcon('https://i.imgur.com/TFDuAHr.png?1');
  }
  return marker;
}

function drawRoute(map, origin, destination) {
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
  
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  directionsService.route({
    origin: origin,
    destination: destination,
    // puedes escoger entre 'WALKING', 'TRANSIT' y 'BICYCLING'
    travelMode: 'DRIVING'
  }, function(response, status) {
    if(status === 'OK') {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    } else {
      alert('No se pudo establecer el recorrido. ', status);
    }
  });
}

function onError(err) {
  console.log(err);
}
```

```css
#map {
  height: 500px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  max-width: 700px;
  width: 100%;
}
.map {
  position: relative;
}
/* simula los estilos de google maps */
button {
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12),
    0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: 'segoe ui';
  font-size: 12px;
  left: 43%;
  padding: .5rem .8rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  z-index: 2;
}
button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
button:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
  <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?"></script>
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body onload="initMap()">
  <section class="map">
    <button id="how-arrive">¿Cómo llegar?</button>
    <div id="map"></div>
  </section>
</body>
</html>
```

### Resultado

Antes de pulsar sobre `¿Cómo llegar?`:

[image]

Luego de pulsar el botón:

[image]

### Demo

Click [aquí](https://codepen.io/mitsug/full/VKyroq/) para ver el demo.

Comment: Es exactamente lo que necesitaba. Disculpas por la demora en responder. Mil gracias y muy informativo!!